# Flutter run a function before the buildcontext with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, mobile, async-await

The problem I have is that I want to run a function before the buildcontext is rendered.
What the function does is read the storage to get the token. The function works with Async Await.
Why do I want to do this?
Because in the build context I have a FutureBuilder and in this I need token data.

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
  dynamic token;
  getToken()async{
    token= await decodeJwt();
    print("first this");
    print(token);
    return token;
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    getToken();
    super.initState();
    
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("after this");
    final profileService=Provider.of<ProfileService>(context);
    final listDropDownService=Provider.of<ListDropDown>(context);
    
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.wait([profileService.getSpecificWalker(token["id"]), listDropDownService.getDropDown("services")]),
      builder: (context,dynamic snapshot){
```

as you can see i used some print also to see what the sequence was like.
But first it prints "then this" and then "first this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My strongest suggestion would be to use some state management solution, such as `flutter_bloc`, that is not directly dependent on the UI components.

If not, then why don't you just try and wrap the `getToken()` method and the `profileService.getSpecificWalker(token["id"])` call in a single async method and call that from the FutureBuilder.

Comment: I am using provider. In any case, if I call it through the provider, it appears as "Future<dynamic>'" . My idea is that on all pages the decodeJWT() can be fired before the page starts. remember that decodeJWT is a function that reads the storage (hence it is async await)
any ideas?

Comment: If all pages always needs the jwt, then make an app-wide-bloc that is always reachable through the context tree. But I think the bigger problem here is a that you force your UI (your pages) to have knowledge about the jwt token. That should reside hidden away in a service and/or some bloc that just serve the UI with the information needed to build the UI.

Comment: In the end I managed to create a function that wrap the two methods.... and then call it from the future as you said. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What you said shows that you need state manager, because in one state you want to get token then when token get available, call the futureBuilder. I recommended [bloC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).

Comment: I am using provider. In any case, if I call it through the provider, it appears as "Future<dynamic>'" . My idea is that on all pages the decodeJWT() can be fired before the page starts. remember that decodeJWT is a function that reads the storage (hence it is async await)
any ideas?

Comment: In this case provider does not help you.

Comment: but if I already use provider . I can't use Bloc too, can I? How would everything be in the main?